# Fastest way to update Winforms ListView items?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, winforms, listview

I have a limited number of listview items that range from 10 to 50 maximum but with multiple columns (10 or so).

I need to update the value of some of these subitems every second. But even with 10 item, it's taking a bit of time where if I try to move the UI, it acts frozen, i.e. responds to my actions slowly.

Here is the update code that updates the ListView itself. I try to do most of the work in another thread that updates prices, etc so the listview only needs to show it.

I am not sure if setting the Text of each subitem is the way to go? It seems not so fast. Or am I better or using WPF that somehow does this faster? I.e. without me having to refresh but rather it refreshed when the data is changed?

```
    void UpdateCoinListView ( )
    {
        this.coinListView.BeginUpdate ( );

        Coin btc = this.Coins [ "BTCUSDT" ];
        if ( btc != null && btc.Price > 0 )
        {
            this.currentPrice.Text = btc.PriceDisplay;
            this.Text = String.Format ( "{0:n0} | {1}%", ( int ) Math.Round ( btc.Price ), btc.PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay );
            this.dataListView.Items [ 1 ].SubItems [ 4 ].Text = btc.AverageDailyPriceDisplay;
        }

        this.coinListView.Columns [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Capital" ] ].Text = MarketData.TotalCapitalInUSDDisplay;
        this.coinListView.Columns [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitAmount" ] ].Text = MarketData.TotalProfitInUSDDisplay;
        this.coinListView.Columns [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Daily" ] ].Text = MarketData.PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay;
        this.coinListView.Columns [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Hourly" ] ].Text = MarketData.PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay;
        this.coinListView.Columns [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Minutely" ] ].Text = MarketData.PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay;

        int index = 0;
        foreach ( var coin in this.Coins.Values )
        {
            var item = this.coinListView.FindItemWithText ( coin.Symbol );

            //var item = this.coinListView.Items [ index ];
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Lowest" ] ].Text = coin.LowestDailyPriceDisplay;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Highest" ] ].Text = coin.HighestDailyPriceDisplay;

            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Empty" ] ].Text = coin.HaveBalance ? coin.ProfitPercentageSigned.ToString ( ) : "-200";
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Capital" ] ].Text = coin.HaveBalance ? coin.CapitalDisplay : "";
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitAmount" ] ].Text = coin.HaveBalance ? coin.ProfitDisplay : "";
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitPercentage" ] ].Text = coin.HaveBalance ? coin.ProfitPercentageDisplay : "";

            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Daily" ] ].Text = coin.PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Hourly" ] ].Text = coin.PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Minutely" ] ].Text = coin.PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "NetVolume" ] ].Text = coin.LastMinuteVolumeInBtcDisplay;

            var volumeColor = coin.LastMinuteVolumeColor;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "NetVolume" ] ].BackColor = volumeColor;

            this.DrawProgressBar ( this.PriceProgressBars [ coin.SymbolPair ], coin.CurrentPricePercentageFromAverage, true, coin.PriceDecimalDisplay );
            if ( coin.HaveBalance )
            {
                int ratio = ( int ) Math.Round ( 100 * Utility.Interpolate ( coin.Price, 0, 2 * coin.Balance.UnitPrice ) );
                this.DrawProgressBar ( this.AveragePriceProgressBars [ coin.SymbolPair ], ratio, false, coin.Balance.UnitPriceDisplay );
            }

            this.DrawProgressBar ( this.VolumeProgressBars [ coin.SymbolPair ], coin.TotalSellVolumePercentage, true, coin.LastHourVolumeInBtcDisplay );

            Color color = Color.White;
            if ( coin.HaveBalance )
            {
                var profitColor = coin.ProfitColor;
                var profitPercentageColor = coin.ProfitPercentageColor;

                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Capital" ] ].ForeColor = profitColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitAmount" ] ].ForeColor = profitColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitPercentage" ] ].ForeColor = profitColor;

                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Symbol" ] ].BackColor = profitPercentageColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Capital" ] ].BackColor = profitPercentageColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitAmount" ] ].BackColor = profitPercentageColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitPercentage" ] ].BackColor = profitPercentageColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Daily" ] ].BackColor = coin.PriceChangeDailyColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Hourly" ] ].BackColor = coin.PriceChangeHourlyColor;
            }
            else
            {
                Color backColor = item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Empty" ] ].BackColor;

                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Capital" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitAmount" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "ProfitPercentage" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Symbol" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Daily" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
                item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Hourly" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
            }


            if ( coin.IsPriceChangeInPercentDailyPositive == NumberSign.Positive )
                color = Green;
            else if ( coin.IsPriceChangeInPercentDailyPositive == NumberSign.Negative )
                color = Red;
            else
                color = Color.White;

            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Daily" ] ].ForeColor = color;


            if ( coin.IsPriceChangeInPercentHourlyPositive == NumberSign.Positive )
                color = Green;
            else if ( coin.IsPriceChangeInPercentHourlyPositive == NumberSign.Negative )
                color = Red;
            else
                color = Color.White;

            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Hourly" ] ].ForeColor = color;


            if ( coin.IsPriceChangeInPercentMinutelyPositive == NumberSign.Positive )
                color = Green;
            else if ( coin.IsPriceChangeInPercentMinutelyPositive == NumberSign.Negative )
                color = Red;
            else
                color = Color.White;

            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Minutely" ] ].ForeColor = color;

            ++index;
        }

        this.coinListView.Sort ( );

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.coinListView.Items.Count ; ++i )
        {
            Color backColor = ( i % 2 == 0 ) ? Color.Black : this.DarkGray;

            var item = this.coinListView.Items [ i ];
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Lowest" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Highest" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "LowPriceAlarm" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "HighPriceAlarm" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
            item.SubItems [ this.ListViewIndices [ "Minutely" ] ].BackColor = backColor;
        }



        this.coinListView.EndUpdate ( );
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if it might be faster if you create an entire new list of updated items (possibly in a separate thread) and then remove all the existing items (using `Clear()`) and use `AddRange()` to add the updated times.

Comment: Thanks that's interesting I can definitely try that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Not sure how to synchronize the updates though, so that they dont overlap.

Comment: you could use DataSource to add/remove/modify data. I think it would be faster and changes would be synchronised.

Comment: @Democrats is there any example of this? I couldnt find anything useable online.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10008/Data-binding-a-ListView

Comment: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/utilities/bindablelistview/source/